# ng multiselect adding onclick not able to select multiple options

Tags: angular, ng-multiselect-dropdown

I am using ng multiselect on my application but i want to refresh the data after when the user click on the multiselect but after adding click on this , multiselect is not working , I can select only one option and it again closes and then I have to again open to select next option

I have added click functionality is there any way , I can set the data again